# AWS SSM, AutoScalingGroup and LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im  kinda of new to AWS. I am using an CLI application in EC2s that needs to receive a command trough the AWS CLI application using the SSM. This CLI application will receive a very high workload which I tought about the autoscaling group for it so it can expand in a certain limit. After so the Application Load Balancer to connect to the ASG. The question that a I wanted to ask is how do I shoot the SSM to the LoadBalancer so it could hit the AutoScaling group just trough a pipeline lets say a jenkins using aws cli? Before I start building something will it work if I attach the ALB and ASG with the cli application installed and then start testing the SSM Commands at the load balancer ips?

Answer (score 0):

> The question that a I wanted to ask is how do I shoot the SSM to the LoadBalancer so it could hit the AutoScaling group just trough a pipeline lets say a jenkins using aws cli?

I'm not sure I understand, but SSM works only through **SSM Agent which is installed on your instances**. It can't be used to execute any `Run Commands` on AWS managed infrastructure, such as ALB.

> Before I start building something will it work if I attach the ALB and ASG with the cli application installed and then start testing the SSM Commands at the load balancer ips?

You can't `Run Commands` directly on ALB. Instead you run it on your instances. Of course, these commands can perform **API actions on the ALB**. But ultimately they run on your instances only.

Hope this helps.